# Delay notifications for Android app a bit and do not send them if they where already noticed

Tags: feature-request, android-app

The notifications of the Android app appear simultaneously to the standard notifications in the top bar inbox. When working on my desktop, I usually notice these notifications and don't need the ones from the app. But currently they appear there nevertheless, resulting in noisy notifications on every of my Android devices running the app.

I'd like to see the Android app notifications delayed (10-60 minutes) and only delivered if I didn't acknowledged the notification in the inbox already.